# how to insert input type="hidden" inside select option

Tags: html, forms

How do I insert a input type="hidden" in the select option without changing the options

here is my code

```
<select name="room" id="room">
  <option value="room1_id">
    room 1 name
    <input type="hidden" value="room 1 price">
  </option>

  <option value="room2_id">
    room 2 name
    <input type="hidden" value="room 2 price">
  </option>
</select>
```

and this the sample my code
[via codepen](https://codepen.io/Code_Senpai/pen/zYqdvgL)

can you fix it?

thank you =)

Answer (score 2):

You can't. `<option>` elements can only have text nodes as their children.

This smells like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You haven't stated the actual problem, but there are a couple of common problems you might be trying to solve:

To get the price on the server-side, use the room ID to look it up in a server-side database.

To get the price on the client-side (e.g. to display a running total using JS) then you could store it in a `data-*` attribute on the `<option>` element.

Answer (score 0):

You can't nest an `<input>` inside an `<option>` but you can nominally link your options and inputs by using predictable `id` attributes such as:

- `room1_option` and `room1_input`
- `room2_option` and `room2_input`

**Example:**

```html
<form>

  <select name="room" id="room">
    <option id="room1_option" value="room1_id">room 1 name</option>
    <option id="room2_option" value="room2_id">room 2 name</option>
  </select> 

  <input id="room1_input" type="hidden" value="room 1 price">
  <input id="room2_input" type="hidden" value="room 2 price">

</form>
```